# How to get GET-Vars via typoscript as value in form field in Ext:form in TYPO3 6.2.32+

Tags: forms, plugins, get, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

After updating a website from TYPO3 6.2.31 to 6.2.35 (ELTS) the following TypoScript code inside a form plugin doesn't work anymore.

```
20 = HIDDEN
20 {
    name = myVar
    value = TEXT
    value.data = GP:myVar
}
```

I don't get the value from the GET var `myVar` into the hidden field.
There were a security issue fixed in 6.2.32

> 2017-08-29 3719867 [RELEASE] Release of TYPO3 ELTS 6.2.32
>
> 2017-08-24 eaa56c9 [SECURITY] Prevent insecure TypoScript processing in EXT:form

Any suggestions how to get it working again?

Comment: ...is there resolved it?